# Getting URL rewrite to work properly with Angular 2

Tags: angular, nginx, angular2-routing, single-page-application

I have an issue with getting the Angular 2 to load the same page upon refresh or upon direct entry (not clicked on by an internal link).

Currently, I have this code for the Angular 2 routing:

```
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { RegistrationComponent }   from './registration/registration.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';



const appRoutes: Routes = [

   { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
   { path: '', component: HomepageComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

To remove the hash sign from the URL and still have it load a page, I have the following Nginx rewrite:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Whenever I try to either refresh or directly enter the /register route, I get redirected to the homepage. Is there a way to stay on the /register page without getting redirected back to the homepage?